# GAMS modelation: how do i set an identifier as the last value of a set (index.last) on an equation

Tags: gams-math

I'm modeling a VRP in GAMS language and one of my equations would ideally be:

```
SUM(i, x(i,n+1)) =e= 0;
```

with "n+1" being the last value of the set i /0*4/ (so it's 4)

I can't type x(i,"4") because this number (4) is just an example.

The software doesn't recognize this equation. the error says "unknown identifier set as index, which i understand is because "n" isn't a set.
so i put n as a set, just like i did with i, but then I'd have to give it a number (3, so that n+1 = 4) and i don't want that.

I just need a way to put "n+1" as a valid index for x(i,n+1)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `x` is declared as `x(i,i)`, you can do something like this:

```
Alias (i,i2);
Equation eq;

eq.. SUM((i,i2)$i2.last, x(i,i2)) =e= 0;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! i thought of that, but originially it's supposed to be: 
SUM(i, x(etc))
and not
SUM((i,i2), x(etc)) 

if i added the "i2" to the SUM, wouldnt it be a different equation?

Comment: The second index if x needs to be controlled somehow, therefor the i2 in the sum. But with the dollar condition, the scope of i2 is limited to exactly one element - the last one. Thus, the equation should be the one you wanted.